# re.match doesn't pick up on txt file format

Tags: python, regex

```
import os.path
import re
def request ():
    print ("What file should I write to?")
    file = input ()
    thing = os.path.exists (file)
    if thing == True:
        start = 0
    elif re.match ("^.+.\txt$", file):
        stuff = open (file, "w")
        stuff.write ("Some text.")
        stuff.close ()
        start = 0
    else:
        start = 1
    go = "yes"
    list1 = (start, file, go)
    return list1
start = 1
while start == 1:
    list1 = request ()
    (start, file, go) = list1
```

Whenever I enter `Thing.txt` as the text, the `elif` should catch that it's in the format given. However, `start` doesn't change to `0`, and a file isn't created. Have I formatted the `re.match` incorrectly?

Comment: `if file.endswith('txt')` and solve your regex problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"^.+.\txt$"` is an incorrect pattern for match `.txt` files you can use the following regex :

```
r'^\w+\.txt$'
```

As `\w` matches word character if you want that the file name only contain letters you could use `[a-zA-Z]` instead :

```
r'^[a-zA-Z]+\.txt$'
```

Note that you need to escape the `.` as is a special sign in regular expression .

```
re.match (r'^\w+\.txt$',file)
```

But as an alternative answer for match file names with special format you can use `endswith()` :

```
file.endswith('.txt')
```

Also instead of `if thing == True` you can just use `if thing :` that is more pythonic !

Answer (score 2):

You should escape second dot and unescape the "t" character:

```
re.match ("^.+\.txt$", file)
```

Also note that you don't really need regex for this, you can simply use `endswith` or search for module that can give you files extensions:

```
import os
fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext('your_file.txt')
```

`fileExtension` is `.txt`, which is exactly what you're looking for.